# Reading in Image of a FITS file ReadHDU doesn't appear to be working in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fits

I am using this library https://github.com/nom-tam-fits/nom-tam-fits#reading-fits-files and I am using it unity in C#

Here is my code

```
Fits f = new Fits(Application.dataPath + "/FITS/SMC-J1634.fits");//, FileAccess.Read);  
        BasicHDU[] hdus = f.Read();

        Debug.Log("HDUS Length" + hdus.Length.ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < hdus.Length; i++)
        {
            //hdus[i].Info();
            Debug.Log(hdus[i].Origin);
        }


        ImageHDU hdu = (ImageHDU)f.ReadHDU();
        int[][] img = (int[][])hdu.Kernel;
```

Reading in the header works fine. Reading in the image gives on errors on the second last line, however the last line gives the error "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" which I assume means the something has gone wrong. If i check if hdu is null it is. I don't understand however why the ReadHDU wouldn't throw some kind of error if it isn't reading correctly.

Any help fixing this would appreciated. I know it is kind of niche but I don't know where to go for help.

Comment: Well, library creator is not contructed to raise error on `ReadHDU()` fail. Maybe you can stap into his code from github and see whats going on

Comment: I have noticed there is an hdus[0].data which I think is where the data is because it has a large array length, but I can't figure how to access elements of the array.